# cqengine compare by datetime

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime, cqengine

I'm trying to find a list of objects that are after a certain `DateTime`. In order to do so, I've created the following query:

```
return foos.retrieve(QueryFactory.equal(EXPIRY_INDEX, new DateTime()));
```

I then created the following index:

```
public static final Attribute<Foo, DateTime> EXPIRY_INDEX = new SimpleAttribute<Foo, DateTime>() {
        @Override
        public DateTime getValue(Foo foo, QueryOptions queryOptions) {
            return foo.getEXPIRY();
        }
};
```

So far all good, except, the `equal(...)` method will invoke `DateTime.equals(...)` as far as I know which will ultimately return `false` all the time. What I need is a way to call `DateTime.isAfterNow(...)` or `DateTime.isAfter(...)`.

How can I find all elements in a collection that have a `DateTime` after right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you should use a greaterThan() query instead of an equals() query.

These will rely on Comparable.compareTo(), instead of Object.equals(). So it should work if your DateTime object implements the Comparable interface properly.

Comment: Thanks, I admire your work, it's truly ahead of its time